# Fibonacci Sequence in C

Tags: c, math

This is the expected output:

[image]

We are to make a C program that calculates for the Fibonacci Sequence.
We're only allowed up to 3 variables and we're NOT allowed to use loops.
And I don't know what to do and how to start.

I hope you guys can help me. :/

Answer (score 22):

On the assumption that you are using 32 bit unsigned integers, the 48th Fibonacci number will cause an integer overflow.  That makes it perfectly feasible to use a lookup table with all the values precalculated (by hand).

Comment: +1 for another solution (only said in comment). To show a possible code would be interesting to stress how the recursive solution, even though recursion may sound alien to him, is the shortest and more intuitive. ... (instead of calc by hand, he could use [this](http://81.167.229.63/~srbzorg/fibonaccigenerator.php) the link comes from wikipedia)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the incredible finitude of the problem and thus the optimal solution. A 192 byte table is probably even smaller than the code would be...not to mention a damn lot faster.

Comment: @R: yes, and if 64 bit integers are used, there are still only 94 numbers before you get to overflow.

Answer (score 17):

Use recursion:

[image]

---

Version in C/C++ language:

```
int fib(int a)
{
    if (a == 0) return 0;
    if (a == 1) return 1;
    return fib(a - 1) + fib(a - 2);
}
```

---

*Apply suggestion from this answer comments:*

Version in C language:

```
/*
 * -1 is a error handler
 */
int fib(int a)
{
    if (a < 0 || a > 47) return -1;
    if (a == 0) return 0;
    if (a == 1) return 1;
    return fib(a - 1) + fib(a - 2);
}
```

Version in C++ language:

```
int fib(int a)
{
    if (a < 0) throw new std::out_of_range("Fibonacci is not defined for negative sign values.");
    if (a > 47) throw new std::overflow_error("Fibonacci for this value was overflow the integer.");
    if (a == 0) return 0;
    if (a == 1) return 1;
    return fib(a - 1) + fib(a - 2);
}
```

Comment: some parts of your code could be simplified like that:  if (a == 0 || a == 1) return  a;

Answer (score 7):

I would suspect that if you can't use loops that your professor/teacher intended you to use recursion. Otherwise it's simply a matter of looking up the proper formula, which makes no sense in a programming class.

If recursion is allowed I highly recomend reading [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson16.html) tutorial (assuming you aren't familiar with it).

Answer (score 7):

If loops and recursion are not allowed, pick up fibonacci sequence definition and do it by hand... it is ridicolously boring and uninteresting but it is the most straightforward solution in those restrictions.

```
a = 0; // 0
b = 1; // 1
a = a + b; // 1
b = a + b; // 2
a = a + b; // 3
b = a + b; // 5
```

and so on: b holds the n-th and a the (n-1)-th number. (Copy-paste `a = a+b; b = a+b;` how many times you need...) Copy-pasting fragments of code is allowed?

... (**edit**) ...

Of course this answer just shows how ridicolous stuffs can get if we put too much rescrictions. If you don't know recursion, you have to learn it, definitively. Or stick into fine mathematics (as other answer shows), but recursion is a powerful tool programmers should know anyway, and the recursive approach is more intuitive than using mathemathical "tricks".

Comment: LAME...and we probably don't want to give rob2k8 even an inkling of an idea that this sort if thing is even REMOTELY acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, it is not... it is just the extreme consequence of prohibiting loops and recursions (since he doesn't know it; so the answer show clearly how silly would it be without even recursion!). The answer is ironically hilarious, and I am sorry to have been forced to write it explicitly; I thought that my final "Copy-pasting fragments of code is allowed?" would have been enough to understand that the answer must not be taken seriously, as you (and your comment upvoter) did.

Comment: ... added details, just in case the OP could become confused and think that the solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html

which you can copy here

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/108426-binets-formula.html

```
long double f(short N) {
    double phi = (1+pow(5,0.5))/2;
    return ceil((pow(phi,N) - pow(1-phi,N))/pow(5,0.5));
}
```

of course, it's just math, but it does calculate fib(N) without recursion and loops.. you still need a way to print all the values for fib(1)..fib(n) though

what your teacher wants is probably recursion.

Comment: this solution stop working from small numbers of fibonacci because floting point variables dont have good precision. And this solution is MPC solution of solve normal recursion.

Comment: integers don't have arbitrary precision either, at least in C. i just wanted to point out that the function does not require an iteration-recursion /per se/

Comment: @Svisstack -- this is no problem -- just write a 256 bit (or so) floating point library and you are good to go.

Comment: let's use GMP then, instead of rewriting it from scratch!

Comment: @Hogan: on 32/64 bit processor this library would be very slow ;-) i think you dont cary about it, and if you dont cary you can use iteral version of fibonacci without insurance of some algorithm breakdown by the floting point precision (256-bit floating point oprations have precision too;-))

Comment: @Svisstack : Why would it be slow?  Besides, it is almost sure to be faster than any kind of loop or recursion.  Of course it depends on your pow() function and your ceil() function, but as written this is O(1) whereas the best you can do with a loop or recursion is O(N).

Comment: @Hogan: but pow() and ceil() you must rewrite in 256bit and at this point your solution is not good because must have too cooding to get solution of from any point in x get error results (from a floating point precision) and ceil() pow() in 256bit may be VERY slow

Comment: @Hogan: pow() is not O(1) because N can be arbitrary large. or from a different perspective: if N is max 256bits the loop or recursion are O(1) as well.

Answer (score 4):

Since loop and recursion aren't allowed,

```
int fib(int n) {
   int fk1 = 0, fk0 = 1;
main_sub3:
   fk1 += fk0;
   fk0 = fk1 - fk0;
   if (n > 0) {
     -- n;
     goto main_sub3;
```

*[raptor](http://xkcd.com/292/)*

Comment: ewwww goto. But, there are raptors.

Comment: for, while, do-while, whatever... are just not-primitive looping mechanisms. A `goto` is the "base" of every loop mechanism (o well, not of all indeed and in a broad sense _recursion_ could be considered a _loop mechanism_ ... but this would be too much :D)

Comment: Anti-goto talk is just propaganda.